# remove space at the end of the line in text file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file

I have got text file with the contents like the below

```
wYFgemq4-IU372t5I-J0UIIdAd-gcojGR7z BA1111111
HoSOtYLI-90yntvqB-2rV/RLiG-BT69R0NV BA1111111
h1uLXWq4-IU2QUkVr-UYuqipiT-byAuoHn7 BG2222222
jL2MFmq4-IU1VLifN-LZmFc+bu-ibc/2IJp GC1111111
zhoZpmq4-IU27lkQ1-kqNLXTbT-ec28qGPR FG1111111
```

but unfortunately there is one more space is adding at the end of 5th line by this I am getting an error when I upload the file ...

How can I remove the space ant the end of the fifth line (i.e)
zhoZpmq4-IU27lkQ1-kqNLXTbT-ec28qGPR FG1111111(at here)

would any one please help on this

and this is my code

```
private bool ParseUploadedDoc(string strUpload)
{
    bool blresult = true;
    strUpload = strUpload.Replace("\r","");
    char [] delimitedchars = {'\n'};
    string[] splitwords = strUpload.Split(delimitedchars);
    string[] column; 
    StringBuilder InvalidCert = new StringBuilder(); 
    StringBuilder InvalidSerial = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string word in splitwords)
    {
        column = word.Split('\t');
        column[1].Trim();
        if (column[0].Length != 35)
        {
            InvalidCert.Append(column[0].ToString());
            InvalidCert.Append(", ");
            blresult = false;
        }
       /// getting error at here
        if (column[1].Length != 9)
        {
            InvalidSerial.Append(column[1].ToString());
            InvalidSerial.Append(", ");
            blresult = false;
        }
    }
    if (blresult == false)
    {
        string strErrCert = "Invalid Certificate Id(s): " + InvalidCert.ToString();
        strErrCert = strErrCert.Substring(0, strErrCert.Length - 2);
        LblInvalidCert.Text = strErrCert;
        string strErrFru = "Invalid Serial Number(s): " + InvalidSerial.ToString();
        strErrFru = strErrFru.Substring(0, strErrFru.Length - 2);
        LblInvalidFru.Text = strErrFru;
    }
    return blresult;
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with: `xyz.Replace(" ", string.empty);`?

Comment: `strUpload = strUpload.TrimEnd()`?

Comment: `text = text.TrimEnd()` ?

Comment: TrimEnd() dint worked for me I tried that one

Comment: Trim() and TrimEnd() don't modify the original string, but return a new one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is at this line

```
column[1].Trim();
```

you should do

```
column[1] = column[1].Trim();
```